# Does focus trigger a keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, onkeyup, onfocus

I made 3 input boxes for time input (hh, mm, ss)
When the user type in 2 digits in hh, it will automatically focus the next (mm) field. Same for mm and ss.

I am using the 'keyup' event to bind my input boxes. However the behaviour is strange:

If I type 2 digits SLOWLY, it works.
If I type FASTER, it will jump twice.

I suspect the 'focus' event triggers the keyup event, and I dont know how to deal with it. I have tried to .preventDefault on the focus event. But no luck.

Here is the code:

```
$('#hh').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var hh = $('#hh').val().toString();
    if (hh.length >= 2) {
        $('#mm').focus();
    }
});

$('#mm').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var mm = $('#mm').val().toString();
    if (mm.length >= 2) {
        $('#ss').focus();
    }
});
```

Here is a demo:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch3ksuwa/) (http://jsfiddle.net/ch3ksuwa)

To reproduce: type in 2 digits quickly in hh field, and it will jump to ss instead of mm

I tried on Chrome and Firefox, same issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ch3ksuwa

Comment: There are rules about putting the code in your post. Using code tags to get around it is bad. Also stackoverflow has snipplets which does basiclaly the same thing as jsFiddle.

Comment: Seems to work fine when testing on Chrome. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @KJPrice I tried both Chrome and FF, no luck

Comment: Try using keypress event. It works on chrome and IE.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `$('#hh').val()` is happening after the second key press but I'm not sure why the second 'keyup' event's target is #mm.

You could try using the 'input' event instead of the 'keyup' event. This event triggers when the input's value is changing. It is more semantic for this purpose and avoids any problems with keyboard events firing at the wrong time.

```
$('#hh').on('input', function (e) {
  var hh = $('#hh').val().toString();
  if (hh.length >= 2) {
    $('#mm').focus();
  }
});

$('#mm').on('input', function (e) {
  var mm = $('#mm').val().toString();
  if (mm.length >= 2) {
    $('#ss').focus();
  }
});
```

I haven't checked which browsers support this yet. It's working on Chrome for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward. The event is triggering twice, if you type fast, because you set "value" to a 2 digit number. Test this by doing this: Type '23', while holding both keys. Then release the 2, it will jump to the second input, then release the 3 and it will jump to the last.

So once you typed two digits in the first input and release one key, the event will be triggered once, and on the second keyup, the next event keyup will be triggered instantly, because the value of the second input is already 2 digits long.

If you replace this with a placeholder, then it works. Check this out:

```
<input type="text" id="ss" class="chained" placeholder="30">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ch3ksuwa/4/

Edit: The first solution I posted fixes this problem in a way, that the second time someone wants to change a value, the same error will occur.

So I have added a variable called "comesFromFirst" which is initially false and will be true, once the keyup event triggers the .focus on the second input. Then, the first time a keyup event is triggered in the second input, it will set the value to false. Now you can also use "value", instead of a placeholder(placeholder is in most cases nicer, tho). Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ch3ksuwa/5/

Relevant jQuery:

```
var comesFromFirst = false;

$('#hh').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var hh = $('#hh').val().toString();
     comesFromFirst = true;
    if (hh.length >= 2) {
        $('#mm').focus();
    }
});

$('#mm').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var mm = $('#mm').val().toString();
    console.log(comesFromFirst);
    if (mm.length >= 2 && comesFromFirst == false) {    
        $('#ss').focus();
    }
    else{
        comesFromFirst = false;  
    }
});
```